# Incrementing (iterating) between two hex values in Python

Tags: python, hex, iteration, increment

I'm learning Python (slowly but surely) but need to write a program that (among other things) increments between two hex values e.g. 30D681 and 3227FF.
I'm having trouble finding the best way to do this. So far I have seen a snippet of code on here that separates the hex into 30, D6 and 81, then works like this-

```
char = 30
 char2 = D6
  char3 = 81

 def doublehex():
    global char,char2,char3
    for x in range(255):
        char = char + 1
        a = str(chr(char)).encode("hex")
        for p in range(255):
           char2 = char2 + 1
           b = str(chr(char2)).encode("hex")
        for y in range(255):
           char3 = char3 + 1
           b = str(chr(char2)).encode("hex")
           c = a+" "+b
           print "test:%s"%(c)
doublehex()
```

Is there a simpler way of incrementing the whole value, e.g. something like

```
char = 30D681
 char2 = 3227FF

 def doublehex():
    global char,char2
   for x in range(255):
        char = char + 1
        a = str(chr(char)).encode("hex")
        for p in range(255):
           char2 = char2 + 1
           b = str(chr(char2)).encode("hex")
           c = a+" "+b
           print "test:%s"%(c)
doublehex()
```

Apologies for my complete ignorance, I really have tried Googling the answer but couldn't find it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just treat the values as integers, and use `xrange()` to range over the two values. Use `format(value, 'X')` to *display* it as hex:

```
start = 0x30D681  # hex literal, gives us a regular integer
end = 0x3227FF

for i in xrange(start, end + 1):
    print format(i, 'X')
```

If your start and end values were entered as hexadecimal strings, use `int(hexvalue, 16)` to turn those into integers first:

```
start = int('30D681', 16)
end = int('3227FF', 16)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Martijn. I knew there'd be a simpler way of doing it! :)