# how to make range in hexadecimal python?

Tags: python

I want to make a range in python from variable a and variable b

```
a = 0x88
b = 0xff
for x range(a, b):
    print(x)
```

from my code the result like this
`136, 137, 138, 139 ...`

but I want the result of looping like this

```
88, 89, 8a, 8b, 8c, 8d, 8e, 8f, 90, 91 .... ff
```

please help me, thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212965/incrementing-iterating-between-two-hex-values-in-python does this answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incrementing (iterating) between two hex values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212965/incrementing-iterating-between-two-hex-values-in-python)

Comment: `print(f"{x:x}")` where the 2nd `x` is the formatting to use.

Comment: You want the result to be the _strings_ `"88"`, `"89"` and etc...? Or a single string `"88, 89, 8a, ..."`? Is this a question about how to display the numbers or the numbers themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hex()` function:

```
a = 0x88
b = 0xff
for x in range(a, b):
    print(hex(x))
```

results in:

```
0x88
0x89
0x8a
0x8b
0x8c
0x8d
0x8e
0x8f
0x90
0x91
0x92
0x93
0x94
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hex(x)` to convert `x` to a hexadecimal number.

Therefore your code will look like this:

```
a = 0x88
b = 0xff
for x in range(a, b):
    print(hex(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Formatting as you asked:

```
a = 0x00
b = 0x100
for x in range(a, b):
    print('{:02x}'.format(x))
```

will generate "88" through "ff"